# iOS Widget creation - To make a Webservice call and populate date like graph

Tags: ios, iphone, widget

I'm new in iOS widget implementation. Just want to check my requirement is applicable for widget creation.

I want to make a web service call and get the data to populate the values like a graph on iOS Widget.

For example : STOCKS app functionality I wanna achieve.

How can i communicate my app and widget. Is it possible to make a service call on TodayViewController.m class.

I went through couple of forums but not getting any solution.

http://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-today-widget--cms-22379

Please let me know your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to make network call (I've done a twitter widget and a RSS widget doing so).
Only restriction you can have is the memory. If you are displaying images in a tableview inside your widget, it can be tricky and crash. Apple allows developpers to use a very small amount of memory so keep that in mind.
For instance in my RSS widget, I have a tableview with three rows and one image inside each row and it's very short in memory (I have memory warnings).

That said, if you want to communicate informations you have received with your widget to your app, it's also possible. I use `NSUserDefaults` to do so, and I synced it between the widget and the app. If you want to use that, don't forget to create a share space between your app and your widget ;)